# Подскажите удобные, простые библиотеки для Python 3 (скачивание файла)

Tags: python, lib

Здравствуйте, не могу найти простые библиотеки для Python 3 (только wget есть) но у него очень мало функций, хотелось бы что-то лучше найти. Подскажите если знаете только для Python 3

Comment: `urllib.request` же, встроена в питон

Comment: "Удобные и простые" это субъективно. К примеру, достаточно удобно и просто для вас `urllib.request.urlretrieve(url, filename)` для скачивания файла? Что значит "мало функций"? Что вы пытаетесь сделать? Попробуйте задать конкретный вопрос: "как сделать X при условии Y, Z"

Answer (score 1):

Что конкретно вы не смогли сделать с помощью wget?
Здесь смотрели? [описание wget на русском](http://www.opennet.ru/man.shtml?topic=wget&category=1)

особенно примеры в конце...

Comment: Wget (lib) которая в Python

Comment: а чем системный wget не устраивает?? Почему обязательно та, что в Python? И вы так и не сказали, что конкретно не смогли сделать wget-том.

Answer (score 0):

Посмотрите библиотеку [grab](https://github.com/lorien/grab). Вот цитата из ее [русскоязычной документации](http://docs.grablib.org/ru/latest/):

> Grab - библиотека для работы с сетевыми документами. Основные области
>   использования Grab:
>
> извлечение данных с веб-сайтов (site scraping) работа с сетевыми API
>   автоматизация работы с веб-сайтами, например, регистратор профилей на
>   каком-либо сайте